# Memory Unit Verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm new with verilog and I'm suppose to create a 64x8 memory unit in verilog with a 16x4 SRAM. I designed it but I don't know how to interpret it into verilog. I do have the 16x4 SRAM and the 2 to 4 decoder but from my understanding is that I need to create a 64x8 which I'm not sure how. Here are my 2 modules I have so far. I know the 64x8 memory unit uses the 2to4 decoder and 8 of the 16x4 SRAM, at least according to my design.

```
module ram16x4(
    input [3:0] adrs,
    inout [3:0] data,
    input chip_en, write_en, output_en
);
reg [0:15][3:0] mem;

assign data = ~chip_en & write_en & ~output_en ? mem[adrs]: 4'hz;

always@(*)
begin
if(chip_en == 0)
    if(write_en == 0 && output_en == 1)
        mem[adrs] = data;
end
endmodule
```

2 To 4 Decoder:

```
module 2to4decoder  (a4, a5, _ce0, _ce1, _ce2, _ce3);

output w, x, y, z;
input a4, a5;

assign _ce0 = (~a4) & (~a5);
assign _ce1 = (~a4) & a5;
assign _ce2 = a4 & (~a5);
assign _ce3 = a4 & a5;

endmodule
```

Comment: Is the question how to build a 64x8 with 16x4 blocks?

Comment: Show us what you think it would look like. Or, what you think a 32x4 and 16x8 will look like. We will correct/guide you from there.

Comment: @Morgan yes that's what I'm trying to figure out, more than likely I just don't understand verilog as well.

Comment: Can you add what you think `module ram64x8` might be to the question, even if it is only instantiating a few 16x4 blocks.

Answer (score 1):

There are some inconsistency in your code (2to4decoder arguments are x,y or ce0, ce1?) so I will answer assuming the following signatures for your modules: (control is active low, as you designed)

```
ram16x4 (
    input [3:0] adrs,
    inout [3:0] data,
    input chip_en,
    input write_en,
    input output_en        
);
module 2to4decoder (
    input a5,
    input a4,
    ouput _ce0,
    ouput _ce1,
    ouput _ce2,
    ouput _ce3
};
```

The solution is based on 2 simple techniques. One for expanding the data (from 4 to 8) and one foe expanding the address space (from 16 to 64):

- data - In order to expand the data (lets say to 16x8 memory) you will need two instances that take the same control signals and different part of the data - one takes bits [3:0] and the other bits [7:4]. Every write and read is performed on **both instances**.
- address space - In order to expand the address space (lets say to 64x4 memory) you should use the 2to4 decoder. This way addresses 0-15 are mapped to instance 0, addresses 16-31 mapped to instance 1 and so on... Every write or read is performed on **only one instance**, according to the address MSBs.

saying all that, the 64x8 solution is based on combining the 2 concepts above and smay look like this: (it can be more elegant when using generate for, but thats another story)

> module ram64x8(
>       input [5:0] adrs,
>       inout [7:0] data,
>       input chip_en, write_en, output_en );
>
> wire ce0, ce1, ce2, ce3;
>
> 2to4decoder decode (
>       .a5   (adrs[5]),
>       .a4   (adrs[4]),
>       ._ce0 (~ce0),
>       ._ce1 (~ce1),
>       ._ce2 (~ce2),
>       ._ce3 (~ce3) );
>
> ram16x4 mem_0_0(
>       .adrs      (adrs[3:0]),
>       .data      (data[**3:0**]),
>       .chip_en   (**ce0**),
>       .write_en  (write_en),
>       .output_en (output_en)        );
>
> ram16x4 mem_0_1(
>       .adrs      (adrs[3:0]),
>       .data      (data[**7:4**]),
>       .chip_en   (**ce0**),
>       .write_en  (write_en),
>       .output_en (output_en)        );
>
> ram16x4 mem_1_0(
>       .adrs      (adrs[3:0]),
>       .data      (data[**3:0**]),
>       .chip_en   (**ce1**),
>       .write_en  (write_en),
>       .output_en (output_en)        );
>
> ram16x4 mem_1_1(
>       .adrs      (adrs[3:0]),
>       .data      (data[**7:4**]),
>       .chip_en   (**ce1**),
>       .write_en  (write_en),
>       .output_en (output_en)        );
>
> ram16x4 mem_2_0(
>       .adrs      (adrs[3:0]),
>       .data      (data[**3:0**]),
>       .chip_en   (**ce2**),
>       .write_en  (write_en),
>       .output_en (output_en)        );
>
> ram16x4 mem_2_1(
>       .adrs      (adrs[3:0]),
>       .data      (data[**7:4**]),
>       .chip_en   (**ce2**),
>       .write_en  (write_en),
>       .output_en (output_en)        );
>
> ram16x4 mem_3_0(
>       .adrs      (adrs[3:0]),
>       .data      (data[**3:0**]),
>       .chip_en   (**ce3**),
>       .write_en  (write_en),
>       .output_en (output_en)        );
>
> ram16x4 mem_3_1(
>       .adrs      (adrs[3:0]),
>       .data      (data[**7:4**]),
>       .chip_en   (**ce3**),
>       .write_en  (write_en),
>       .output_en (output_en)        );
>
> endmodule